# Facebook comments color scheme won't change

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-comments

Trying to add the official Facebook comments plugin. plugin loads fine but I cannot change the theme or color scheme.

According to [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/):

`colorscheme` is one of the settings for the plugin and it's controlled via a custom html5 attribute. That attribute is `data-colorscheme`.

> The color scheme used by the comments plugin. Can be "light" or "dark".

I want the dark color scheme, wouldn't that be `data-colorscheme="dark"`?

I tried that and it doesn't have any effect.

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments#configurator" data-colorscheme="dark" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments#configurator" data-numposts="5"></div>
```

here's my full code.

```html
<body>

  <div id="fb-root"></div> <!-- load sdk -->
  <script>
    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s);
      js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.10";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  </script>
  
  <div></div> <!-- page content -->
  <div></div> <!-- page content -->
  <div></div> <!-- page content -->
  <div></div> <!-- page content -->
  <div></div> <!-- page content -->
  <div></div> <!-- page content -->
  <div></div> <!-- page content -->
  <div></div> <!-- page content -->
  
  <div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments#configurator" data-colorscheme="dark" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments#configurator" data-numposts="5"></div> <!-- FB comments with attr data-colorscheme="dark"  -->


</body>
```

Comment: I am not sure if that still exists, I think I remember that they removed this at some point ... probably did not update the docs accordingly.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer? My facebook comments on my dark website are unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

You add `data-href=""` property two times.
Please try this:

```
<section>
    <div class="fb-comments" data-href="{{url absolute="true"}}" data-width="100%" data-colorscheme="dark" data-numposts="5"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments#configurator" data-colorscheme="dark" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments#configurator" data-numposts="5"></div>
```

Try this one

```
<fb:comments href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments#configurator" num_posts="5" width="100%" colorscheme="dark"></fb:comments>
```

Comment: `<fb:comments>` isn't valid html, "fb" is not a valid namespace and AFAIK not documented on facebook docs